# Can a contract be the owner of another contract and kill it?

Tags: solidity, contract-design

How can contract B (created and owned by contract A) verify that contract A invoked the kill method? (Is `msg.sender` the same for contract A and B or is `msg.sender` the address of contract A when A calls B)

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can. If you write your contract as `owned` based in this other contract which I show here below (same as written in the [ethereum.org token tutorial](https://www.ethereum.org/token)), it can.

```
contract owned {
    address public owner;

    function owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
        _
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}
```

If you want to make the original executor of the contract A the owner of the contract B you would only have to change `owner = msg.sender;`for `owner = tx.origin,` in the owned contract.

Comment: So in other words, when I initiate a transaction on contract A and A internally makes a sub-transaction on B, B will see A as `msg.sender` and not the original initiator of the transaction?

Comment: Yes, the initiator of the transaction would be  the `tx.origin`.