# get address of contract which called other contract

Tags: contract-development

What are some ways to get address of contract which called a contract ?

For example, does `msg.sender` pass the address of the account which invoked `callCanOnlyBeCalledByB()`, or the address of B ?

```
contract A {
    address B; //set by other mechanism
    function canOnlyBeCalledByB() external {
        if(msg.sender == B) { do thing }
    }
}

contract B {
    address owner; //set by other mechanism
    address A; //set by other mechanism

    function callCanOnlyBeCalledByB() {
        if(msg.sender != owner) throw;
        bytes4 functionSig = bytes4(sha3("canOnlyBeCalledByB()"));    
        A.call(functionSig);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code uses `msg.sender` correctly as explained by @Edmund.  Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract (or address) that called your contract is `msg.sender`, as I think your example intends. So if you call B then B calls A, B sees your address in `msg.sender`, then A sees B's address in `msg.sender`.

The externally owned account that triggered the original chain of calls is available as `tx.origin`. So `tx.origin` will contain your address, in both A and B. It's generally considered bad practice to discriminate between humans and contracts, so you don't usually want to be using `tx.origin`.