# User Management in private ethereum block chain app

Tags: security, accounts

I am doing a POC block chain application, not a crypto currency once.

I saw many examples determining user by using **msg.sender** attribute, my question is can we manage users in block chain app like we do in regular applications?

Or

Do all users need to have an EOA type account ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to interact with a Dapp users should have an account because they need to send transactions (Normaly users use a Dapp Browser which has a built-in account manager). `msg.sender` provides you the sender's address (it could be a contract) read about `msg.sender` and `tx.origine` : [What's the difference between 'msg.sender' and 'tx.origin'?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin)

Comment: what is a dapp browser ? when you mean account it is EOA right? if it is EOA how can we have attributes like username etc for it? because all we have is an address.

Comment: Dapp browser is the app used by users to interact with your Dapp eg: MIST. the network is supposed to be anonymous so you should setup an identity system (users send their credentials withing transactions to your *Dapp)or search for an existing one based on ethereum.