# isContract function using EVM assembly to get the address' code size

Tags: solidity, contract-development, accounts, evm, assembly

My problem is that I need to make sure my contract processes only the transactions coming from EOA (externally owned accounts). For this I need to determine the type of account I'm dealing with. In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644395/how-to-find-out-if-an-ethereum-address-is-a-contract) I found a solution, here's the code:

```
function isContract(address addr) returns (bool) {
  uint size;
  assembly { size := extcodesize(addr) }
  return size > 0;
}
```

Since I don't understand assembly at all, I have no idea what's going on there.

- Does this function work as described?
- Is there a way for a contract to fool it?
- Will this function work when the network transitions to POS?

Thank you!

Comment: A separate question explaining why "I need to make sure my contract processes only the transactions coming from EOA" may also be helpful.  In most cases, it is not recommended to discriminate against contracts because your system won't be as flexible and interoperable.  For example, blockchains can be helpful with IoT because they can allow "things" to make and receive payments.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15641/how-does-a-contract-find-out-if-another-address-is-a-contract

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**EDIT:** The function will return false if it is invoked from a contract's constructor (because the contract has not been deployed yet).

The code should be used very carefully, if at all, to avoid security hacks such as:

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/916xni/how_to_pwn_fomo3d_a_beginners_guide/ ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20190105222409/https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/916xni/how_to_pwn_fomo3d_a_beginners_guide))

To [repeat](http://web.archive.org/web/20180128183802/https://medium.com/@matthewdif/mechanism-design-security-in-smart-contracts-87f08555b38b):

**Do not use the EXTCODESIZE check to prevent smart contracts from calling a function. This is not foolproof, it can be subverted by a constructor call, due to the fact that while the constructor is running, EXTCODESIZE for that address returns 0.**

**See [sample code](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/64340/42) for a contract that tricks EXTCODESIZE to return 0.**

---

If you want to make sure that an externally owned account (EOA) is calling your contract, a simple way is `require(msg.sender == tx.origin)`. However, preventing a contract is an [anti-pattern](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/683) with [security](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/security-considerations.html#tx-origin) and [interoperability](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin) considerations.

This will need revisiting when account abstraction is implemented.

---

<s>Prior answer.</s>

**Yes,** the function works.

EXTCODESIZE is the EVM opcode for getting the size of the code at an address.

> 0x3b    EXTCODESIZE     Get size of an account's code

A contract cannot fool EXTCODESIZE to return zero for the contract's size.

Also, an externally owned account (EOA) cannot fool this code into making it think that the EOA is a contract.  This is because an EOA has no code (zero length) and you can't put code into an EOA any more feasibly than it is to find the private key of a contract.

The function does not have any dependency on Proof of Stake and will continue working.

Comment: This does not depend on POS, but it will change due to account abstraction in Serenity. I would not rely on this continuing to work forever, and agree that there is essentially no reason why it should matter whether an account is a contract or not

Comment: @TjadenHess Which part will change? Or should this be a separate question? It seems reliable that the definition of a contract would be an account that has code...

Comment: In Serenity, the idea is that *every* account will be a contract, i.e. normal accounts will have ECDSA verification code

Comment: https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/12/24/understanding-serenity-part-i-abstraction/

Comment: ~EXTCODESIZE` is usually zero in the constructor of a contract.
You might want to check this out:
https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/916xni/how_to_pwn_fomo3d_a_beginners_guide/?__twitter_impression=true

Comment: This answer is incorrect, see PhABC's answer below. I wonder how many developers have been misguided into writing vulnerable contracts because of this post.

Comment: @Adibas03 and DanielQue Thanks for the alarm and answer updated. This won't be the last time that a hacker will find a flaw in a technique.

Comment: @TjadenHess the Serenity blog was posted almost 3 years ago. As far as I know, EOAs are still in play. Has the implementation of only one account type been abandoned? I would like to restrict my function to calls from external contracts only (no EOAs), but if `extcodesize` will soon return non-zero values for what was once external accounts, I need to avoid this shortcut.

Comment: Account abstraction is still in the works, you can see a more recent discussion here: https://ethresear.ch/t/a-recap-of-where-we-are-at-on-account-abstraction/1721

Answer (score 8):

This code snippet is correct, although it seems important to note that `EXTCODESIZE` will return 0 when called within the `constructor` of a contract, since the contract is not created yet. Hence, if `msg.sender` is a contract, the `isContract()` modifier could return false if your contract's function is called within the constructor of the `msg.sender` contract. This attack vector has been used on various occasions, such as draining the [FoMo3D's ETH "airdrop pot"](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa62142888aba8370742be823c1782d17a0389da1#code).

A solution to this would be to (A) require `msg.sender` to provide an ECDSA signature for their first function call, (B) require `msg.sender` to call your contract on two separate blocks or (C) add  `require(msg.sender == tx.origin)`. The latter would be the cheapest, followed by ECDSA and the most expensive would be the 2 step process.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your given solution? Thanks!