# How does a contract find out if another address is a contract?

Tags: solidity, accounts, addresses, evm

Is it possible, from within a contract written in Solidity, to check if a contract is placed on a specific address or if this address does not contain any code?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This works:

```
function isContract(address _addr) private returns (bool isContract){
  uint32 size;
  assembly {
    size := extcodesize(_addr)
  }
  return (size > 0);
}
```

The assembly language that all Ethereum contracts compile down to contains an opcode for this precise operation: `EXTCODESIZE`. This opcode returns the size of the code on an address. If the size is larger than zero, the address is a contract. But you need to write assembly code within the contract to access this opcode since the Solidity compiler does not support it directly at the moment. The above code creates a private method that you can call from within your contract to check if another address contains code. If you don't want a private method, remove the private keyword from the function header.

**Edit: `EXTCODESIZE` returns 0 if it is called from the constructor of a contract. So if you are using this in a security sensitive setting, you would have to consider if this is a problem.**

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this is the best method we have for checking whether an address is a contract right now. But anyone using this solution should also know that it's possible for a contract to return 0 from `EXTCODESIZE` if the function call was made from within that contracts constructor. This means that you can't blindly use `EXCODESIZE` to prevent other contracts from interacting with yours, it must be used with caution.

Comment: I originally needed this since I had created my own ERC20 token contracts and some financial contracts that transferred these tokens. When the financial contracts where settled, they were deleted by calling `selfdestruct`. As a security measure, I did not want the ERC20 to be transfer funds to deleted financial contracts so I introduced this check. For this use case, this check works but for other use cases, the Rob Hitchens B9lab warning should be heeded.

Comment: After 0.8.1 one can also use this snippet without loss of efficiency (though one should still take the same aforementioned caution):


`function isContract(address addr) private returns (bool isContract) {
   return addr.code.length > 0;
}`

Comment: +1 Thanks! I see this in WUST contract on BSC chain, and I wonder myself. For reference of real usage in real project https://bscscan.com/address/0x23396cF899Ca06c4472205fC903bDB4de249D6fC#code

Answer (score 23):

Full credit to @AnAllergyToAnalogy for the caution item.

I made an example to demonstrate that a `constructor` will trick this method. Posting for others who might come across this thread.

In practice, `isContract` can't reliably detect an attacker calling from a constructor.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Victim {

    function isContract() public view returns(bool){
      uint32 size;
      address a = msg.sender;
      assembly {
        size := extcodesize(a)
      }
      return (size > 0);
    }

}

contract Attacker {
    
    bool public iTrickedIt;
    Victim v;
    
    constructor(address _v) public {
        v = Victim(_v);
        // addrss(this) doesn't have code, yet
        iTrickedIt = !v.isContract();
    }
}
```

- deploy Victim
- deploy Attacker with Victim address
- check `iTrickedIt` in Attacker

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

`Address.sol` in OpenZeppelin/contracts/utility has function `isContract` that works on the principle described. Same warning applies. Use with awareness.

Comment: As @eth below says, we can use require(msg.sender == tx.origin). Many says it has security vulnerabilities.  I am sure it would be for other cases. But in my case, I just want to know caller is contract or not. I dont want other contracts from interacting with my contract whatsoever. so is it safe to use this, just for this use case?  Thank again in advance for your time!

Comment: The answer is very good, in my opinion. Also the source is very respectablr. I would heed the warnings.

Answer (score 18):

Since this is security related, it's helpful to emphasize
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644395/how-to-find-out-if-an-ethereum-address-is-a-contract:

**The top-voted answer with the `isContract` function that uses EXTCODESIZE was discovered to be hackable.**

The function will return false if it is invoked from a contract's constructor (because the contract has not been deployed yet).

The code should be used very carefully, if at all, to avoid security hacks such as:

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/916xni/how_to_pwn_fomo3d_a_beginners_guide ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20190105222409/https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/916xni/how_to_pwn_fomo3d_a_beginners_guide))

To [repeat](http://web.archive.org/web/20180128183802/https://medium.com/@matthewdif/mechanism-design-security-in-smart-contracts-87f08555b38b):

**Do not use the EXTCODESIZE check to prevent smart contracts from calling a function. This is not foolproof, it can be subverted by a constructor call, due to the fact that while the constructor is running, EXTCODESIZE for that address returns 0.**

**See [sample code](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/64340/42) for a contract that tricks EXTCODESIZE to return 0.**

---

If you want to make sure that an EOA is calling your contract, a simple way is `require(msg.sender == tx.origin)`. However, preventing a contract is an [anti-pattern](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/683) with [security](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/security-considerations.html#tx-origin) and [interoperability](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin) considerations.

This will need revisiting when account abstraction is implemented.

Answer (score 9):

### Update for Solidity v0.8 and Above

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

function isContract(address _addr) view returns (bool) {
    return _addr.code.length > 0;
}
```

Note that all security caveats mentioned in the other comments **still** apply.

Answer (score 5):

I'm working on this as well. There is an opcode called `extcodehash`. It [says](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1052.md)

> The EXTCODEHASH of the account without code is c5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470 what is the keccack256 hash of empty data

So I think there is a possibility to check `isContract` by using this `extcodehash` combined with the `c5d2460186f72...`

```
function isContract(address addr) internal view returns (bool) {
    bytes32 accountHash = 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470;

    bytes32 codehash;
    assembly {
        codehash := extcodehash(addr)
    }
    return (codehash != 0x0 && codehash != accountHash);
}
```

This means, if the code hash does not equal to 0 nor `c5d2460186f72...`, we can conclude this is the contract address?

Comment: We would need a test to see if we can trick your approach with a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

One obvious point not emphasized in previously posted answers is that, YES, requiring

```
assembly {
size := extcodesize(_addr)
}
```

will guarantee that only a contract can make it past the check if `size > 0`.

However, the opposite check to see that a sender is NOT a contract (but an EOA) is much more complicated and requires a signature verification scheme in order to prove. There are 2 approaches, which you can read up on more [here](https://blog.openzeppelin.com/bypassing-smart-contract-timelocks/) and [here](https://weka.medium.com/how-to-send-ether-to-11-440-people-187e332566b7).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to check and make sure that an address is not a contract, is by comparing tx.origin with msg.sender. You could do a modifier for that.

```js
    modifier onlyEoa() {
        require(tx.origin == msg.sender, "Not EOA");
        _;
    }
```

`address.code.length > 0` is not always a good solution because if a contract calls your contract from its constructor, then `address.code.length` will be 0 because the attacking contract has not been constructed yet, tricking you into thinking that is not a contract.

More info in this response: [Is there any simple function done in Solidity to check if an address is a contract address or a wallet address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/133767/is-there-any-simple-function-done-in-solidity-to-check-if-an-address-is-a-contra)