# Is there a way to know the contract creation Address from a the transaction?

Tags: blockchain, ethereumj

I know that in the transaction receipt I can get the contract address by getting a transaction receipt from a generated transaction.

But I am wondering since smart contract addresses are deterministic in some sense if there is a way to predict the address from the transaction its self, not the receipt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I actually found the answer my self sadly things are not updated in the documentation at least so far, however, there is a `creates` field in every transaction.

So when you, for example, do `getBlock` and get all blocks including `transactions` you can find if it was a contract creation transaction first by checking if `to` is zero which is mentioned in the documentation and `creates` as the address.

Comment: Can you leave a reference to documentation or json example.

Comment: contract address is contained in the receipt of the transaction: eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash).ContractAddress

Comment: @Nulik your answer is not correct. I don't want it from the transaction receipt

Answer (score 4):

@Nulik has the answer that is the clearest.

The only caveat is the actual command is `eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash).contractAddress`

If you are using `Web3`, use `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash).contractAddress`.

([Info on how to use Web3 in Python](https://medium.com/validitylabs/how-to-interact-with-the-ethereum-blockchain-and-create-a-database-with-python-and-sql-3dcbd579b3c0))

Comment: The whole point is getting the address without `getTransactionReceipt` so its not the right answer at all 

"I know that in the transaction receipt I can get the contract address by getting a transaction receipt from a generated transaction."

Read the question clearly next time

Comment: @MoeElsharif Sorry...you are right. If you know the transaction creator address and the next nonce used (would have to be non-random), you can predict the next contract address. There is a CTF at this link -- https://blockchain-ctf.securityinnovation.com/#/ -- called `TrustFund` whose challenge is just this. But see https://slack-files.com/T0J0350JF-FK5NTH41J-d83c8daf88 for an example of how to see this information in Etherscan.

Comment: @MoeElsharif By the way, I think what was confused me was your best answer to your question, which doesn't seem to answer your question either. In your question you are asking "[is there] a way to predict the address from the transaction its self" (i.e., predicting addresses). Then in your answer, you are explaining how you can find the contract address of an already existing contract through the getBlocks function... Perhaps you forgot (both before and now) what your question really was.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually get the contract address before a transaction is generated. A contract's address is determined by the address and nonce of the contract creator.

From the [source code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/crypto/crypto.go#L74):

```
func CreateAddress(b common.Address, nonce uint64) common.Address {
    data, _ := rlp.EncodeToBytes([]interface{}{b, nonce})
    return common.BytesToAddress(Keccak256(data)[12:])
}
```