# How can I get contract address from tx_hash which is contract transaction?

Tags: contract-development

The following is a contract transaction. I want to get the created contract address from the tx_hash using JSON RPC or web3. Is it possible?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb4c93e32218f1688343334e5c1b12c2d9c523516dc3644c98865a93ec3230c73

---

Update 1

I found the similar question. Moe mentioned the solution. I'm looking into it right now.

[Is there a way to know the contract creation Address from a the transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32106/is-there-a-way-to-know-the-contract-creation-address-from-a-the-transaction)

Answer (score 1):

I found the way.

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionReceipt","params":["0xb4c93e32218f1688343334e5c1b12c2d9c523516dc3644c98865a93ec3230c73"],"id":1}' http://localhost:xxx
```