# How to differentiate a smart contract from a common wallet?

Tags: web3js, tokens, erc-20, wallets

Having an Ethereum address, I need to check whether it is a wallet or a token (ERC-20 contract).

How to check? (I need to implement it with Web3js.)

Ideally, it should also reject contracts which are not ERC-20.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28521/how-to-detect-if-an-address-is-a-contract

Answer (score 1):

Similar question to [How to detect if an address is a contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28521/how-to-detect-if-an-address-is-a-contract?noredirect=1&lq=1)

you can refer to [getcode](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetcode)

if the address is representing an External Owned Account you will get 0x as response otherwise you will get the contract's bytecodeode. for example :

```
var code = web3.eth.getCode("0xd5677cf67b5aa051bb40496e68ad359eb97cfbf8");
console.log(code); // "0x600160008035811a818181146012578301005b601b6001356025565b8060005260206000f25b600060078202905091905056"
```