# How do you know if a contract is destroyed?

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-invocation, web3.py, selfdestruct

I'm using web3.py to interact with contracts. I was wondering, after calling a function with `selfdestruct` or `suicide(address)`, how do I find out that the contract is in fact dead?

Comment: Try to call any read-only function of that contract, and verifies that it raises an exception.

Comment: @goodvibration Is there any smarter ways other than relying on exceptions?

Comment: It is indeed not a very reliable method, because the call can fail for other reasons (for example, you're not even connected to the node). So you're bound to check the error message, which may vary depending on your web3 provider.

Comment: Why not just check if there is a contract at the address? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/15642/31933

Comment: @LauriPeltonen Can we do something like this in web3 or evm manager API instead of from another contract?

Comment: ah, a better alternative was already provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`eth.getCode`](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.getCode) to see if there is code at the address. If there is no code, there is no contract. If there is code, there is a contract associated with the address.

Using `ether.js`, you can see how it works below. The first call was after the contract was deployed and the second call was after it was `selfdestruct`ed.

```
> kovanEthersProvider.getCode('0x761f887ea907DB3FBc13f55867Db2c2c9BDB34F9').then(console.log) 
0x6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b506004361060285760003560e01c8063b9554c5914602d575b600080fd5b60336035565b005b600073ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16fffea265627a7a723158203c431b72fff6bd29b3dd6d5b1c73f87aa200fb5a5029cbc24f45dac0e030d52664736f6c63430005110032

> kovanEthersProvider.getCode('0x761f887ea907DB3FBc13f55867Db2c2c9BDB34F9').then(console.log)
0x
```

Follow the same pattern with `web3.py`.