# Find out if an address is contractual at browser/web server level

Tags: contract-development

I'm using ruby and would like to find out if an address is a contract one that can potentially take a lot of gas to transfer money to (and possibly failed in the middle).

In this: 
[Using EVM assembly to get the address' code size](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/14015/using-evm-assembly-to-get-the-address-code-size/14016#14016)

They suggesting to use this code:

```
function isContract(address addr) returns (bool) {
  uint size;
  assembly { size := extcodesize(addr) }
  return size > 0;
}
```

I think this is to be executed inside ETH miner itself?
If I want to perform a simple check on my browser/Ruby on Rails server, how should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Ethereum node's RPC interface described here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC. You're interested in this function here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getcode. You can use curl to request the data.