# How can I tell who has called a function / contract?

Tags: contract-invocation, embark

I am very new to Ethereum and don't really understand the problem spec very well, so bear with me.

There is a function named GetVotesCount() in the contract MordorVote which I must limit to only being called by a 'vote master'. How can I determine who is calling a function in the contract?

Also, when I invoke a function in Embark, I get a hex string returned, but not whatever the function returns. How can I find out what a function is returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `msg.sender` will have the address of the caller.  In your function you can do `if (msg.sender != addressOfVoteMaster) throw;`.

See also: [What's the difference between 'msg.sender' and 'tx.origin'?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin)

2. You get a hex string, which is the transaction hash.  Depending on the type of function, you could make it `constant` to get the function's return value.  See
   [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call)

Comment: Thanks.

Also, how should I determine the address of vote master? Is that just an IP address? (so 127.0.0.1?)


Unrelated to this question, but I cannot post another question; do you know how I can increase my gas? I am trying to test a contract given to me, but I can no longer call some functions due to being out of gas.

Comment: This example may help you: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#subcurrency-example  Like it, the simplest might be to have the vote master be the one to deploy the contract.  To increase the gas, in the transaction object add a gas property like: `{from: ..., gas: 1000000}`.  As a new user, you may need to give some time between asking questions.  We'll have to continue there.  Also, the 2 questions here aren't related so should be asked separately in the future.