# What are legitimate uses of tx.origin?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, security

It is known that `msg.sender` must be used for authentication instead of `tx.origin` (the difference explained [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1891/5113)). Some static analysis tools (e.g., in [Remix](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/)) detect all usages of `tx.origin` as potential vulnerabilities and advise to use `msg.sender` instead.

What are the use cases where `tx.origin` is legitimate? If there are none, is `tx.origin` going to be deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of two semi-legitimate use cases:

- If you, for some reason, want to block an address from interacting with your contract, `tx.origin` would be more appropriate because the owner of the address can't use a contract as a middleman to circumvent your block.

  Note that this block would of course only block an address, not a person. Any human can just create a new address and use that one. This block could also be circumvented using external oracle, timer or other types of services that can provide a callback.
- You may want to record which people use your contract most, and add some counters in your contract to keep track of it. If you only want to count the 'human addresses' that originally initiated the use of your contract, you should use `tx.origin` instead of `msg.sender`.

I would personally be fine with the deprecation and removal of `tx.origin`. Contract functions should idealistically be unaware of whether a human or another contract is calling it.

I'm not aware of any current plans to remove it.

Answer (score 4):

You can only use `tx.origin` when you are interested in the user, but security isn't a concern. I'm open-minded but I've yet to see a compelling case that fits both requirements simultaneously. It's a wonderful idea in principle, but since it has a vulnerability in practice, it's a "do not use" *in my opinion*.

Answer (score 4):

If a smart contract, and not some EOA, is calling you:

tx.origin != msg.sender

This can permit you to manage if you are interested in knowing that.

Answer (score 3):

Using a [CloneFactory](https://github.com/optionality/clone-factory) is a legitimate reason to use `tx.origin` if you want to set the owner correctly. Since you would usually write something like this in the constructor:

```
owner = msg.sender
```

However, when using the `CloneFactory` this would actually be the `CloneFactoryContract`. Therefore, setting the owner instead to `tx.origin` is the solution. After deployment, all other checks won't use the `tx.origin`:

`require(msg.sender == owner)`

So it's only about setting the correct owner when deploying the contract.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/683 argued for the removal of `tx.origin` because it was often misused.

It also includes a use case by HarryR for using `tx.origin`:

> For example, I want to verify the call chain of a transaction, to
>   ensure that it originated from a user, and that it passed through
>   exactly two other contracts (which are on my whitelist) before
>   reaching me.

To sum up, the most obvious legitimate uses of `tx.origin` is for checking the call chain (not the *type* of accounts in the call chain).  This is consistent with the probable intent of the authors of the EVM and they did not want contracts to be discriminated against.

An advanced example is in @Markus' answer.

Comment: tx.origin is also used as an index for array. Kindly see the example at: https://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/solidity-tutorial

Comment: @zak100 Thanks for the example. It's a tutorial so I can understand it aims for a certain level of simplicity. Here's a [crowdsale example](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol)  In general you can see that a big library like OpenZeppelin has [been able to avoid tx.origin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/search?q=tx.origin)