# Tx.origin and msg.sender when sending signed Raw transaction

Tags: solidity, raw-transaction, signature

A client with address **A** signs a raw transaction, and leaves it all ready to be sent, gives it to the server with address **B**, which later will send it with sendSignedTransaction(...).

What will be the values of:

- > msg.sender
- > tx.origin

EDIT: Notice this is NOT a duplicate of [this other question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin), since in the other question the answers and the questions are oriented towards contract vs. non-contract addresses, whereas here both addresses **A** and **B** are not contracts, but in this case **A** signs and server with address **B** sends.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between 'msg.sender' and 'tx.origin'?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin)

Comment: Do you know/can explain how we can sign a transaction without sending it?

Comment: @willjgriff The situation you are saying is not possible in Ethereum, if A signed the transaction then B cannot sign it again. He can broadcast the transaction on behalf of A.

Answer (score 4):

`msg.sender` and `tx.origin` will be the same (the account that signed the transaction). Neither relates to which servers were involved in transmitting the data.

Comment: This must be correct, otherwise there could be issues with anything that relies on `msg.sender` representing the owner of a public private key pair eg the ERC20 standard.

Answer (score 2):

The Ethereum Virtual Machine is part of the *consensus layer* of Ethereum. It does not know anything about nodes or IP addresses, which are part of the *network layer* of Ethereum.

Therefore, `msg.sender` and `tx.origin` must have the same value, regardless of who broadcast it.