# Correct way of sending Token via contract

Tags: contract-development, erc-20

```
[Sender] -> [My Contract] -> [ERC20 Contract]
```

The sender invokes **my Contract**, and **my contract** in turns will invoke **ERC20 contract** to Transfer token on behalf of the senders (using his **msg.sender**).

However, the **ERC20 contracts** Transfer() function **msg.sender** will become the **My Contract**'s address instead of the **Sender**'s address.

May I know what is the correct way for **My Contract** to Transfer a Token on behalf the **Sender**?

Comment: This might be relevant: [What's the difference between 'msg.sender' and 'tx.origin'?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin)

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi I don't think it is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this using the ERC20 `transfer(..)` function.

You will need to call the `transferFrom(..)` function on the ERC20 contract.

To be able to use `transferFrom(..)`, your `[Sender]` will first have to call `approve(..)` on the ERC20 contract to allow your contract to use `transferFrom(..)`.

Comment: My contact cannot call approve on behalf of the sender. If the sender can call approve himself, why not he just send the token directly to the other contract? This method is a bit redundant and gas wasting

Comment: @sk You wanted your contract to transfer on behalf of the sender. If the sender did not need to give permission, any contract could steal anyone's tokens. That's why an approval is necessary.

Comment: @Jessee, I was hoping someone come out with ERC677 or even a better idea. IMHO the transfer / approve mechanism in ERC20 is flaw, it waste gas, and creates a race condition (non thread safe)

Comment: @sk I agree. ERC223 or ERC677 would be better suited to this purpose, but your question was about an ERC20 contract :)