# msg.sender in solidity

Tags: solidity, myetherwallet

I have read that msg.sender is the address of the person interacting with the blockchain. Does it mean a wallet address ? Do we always specify an address when we interact with contract i.e. deploy as well as web3.js calls ?

Also, the address is publicly known,  so is there a role of a private key/json file stored which only a owner of a wallet have ? (Public/Private key communication like ssh).

Answer (score 2):

`msg.sender` is the address of the caller of the current contract. `msg.sender` could be either a smart contract or a wallet (external account).

There's also `tx.origin`, which what you described: the signer of the transaction in which the call was made. That's always an external account. Use it with care, though.

[More info here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin)

Comment: What address ? Wallet/account address ?