# Instantiating a contract inside another contract on behalf of some address

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

I want to initialise an instance of a contract inside another contract on behalf of some address.

e.g. I have contracts A and B

```
contract A{
    address owner;

    constructor() public{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

and I want to instantiate this contract inside B as follows

```
contract B{
    A instance = new A();   // I'm talking about this instance
}
```

so, I want here is that the *instance is created on behalf of the caller(either deployer of contract B or through some function)*.

i.e. The owner setup in the `instance` of A is the caller.

How can I do so?

---

#### Clearer example

I have two contracts A & B, and I create an instance of contract A inside B.

Contract A has a function, say *anyFunction()*.

```
contract B{
    A instance;

    function anotherFunction() public{
        A.anyFunction();
    }

}
```

If I call `anotherFunction()`, how can I make it sure that the call made to function `anyFunction()` is on behalf of the **caller of `anotherFunction()`**, and not on behalf of contract B.

Comment: If you're the one writing `A`, just have it take the owner as a parameter. But there's (thankfully) no way to fake the value of `msg.sender`.

Comment: I don't want to fake it.

Just want to know, if there is any way possible, any way, in which I can call functions of contract A, using its instance, as if it has come from the sender of the request.

Comment: ....and not from the contract B

Comment: You say you don't want to fake `msg.sender`, but then you ask how. :-) It's hard to suggest other solutions to your problem because I don't know what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: oh. I took it in another sense. :D

Comment: I just want to do, that I've written in the last comment. Is it possible anyway?

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it's unanswerable in its current form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94967/discussion-between-aman-pandey-and-smarx).

Answer (score 2):

The only direct options you have are `msg.sender` and `tx.origin` (which shouldn't be used basically ever). There is no way to get addresses which are "between" these addresses.

Otherwise, as smarx stated, you should pass the desired owner address as a parameter and use that.

Answer (score 0):

use `tx.origin` (you MUST read my last statement before use it). It will understand that the one who call the anotherContract is the sender. You can read more at this question answer: [What's the difference between 'msg.sender' and 'tx.origin'?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin). But use it with caution because IT IS VERY DANGEROUS: https://link.medium.com/x1bLy7S9yX

Comment: hey @haxeri , I'm not sure, but is there something like tx.sender? Do you mean to say msg.sender.

or, maybe you want to say tx.origin.

Quite unsure right now.