# What does msg.sender == tx.origin actually do? Why?

Tags: msg.sender

A lot of contracts use require(msg.sender == tx.origin)

What is the purpose of it?

When should you add this code?

What difference does it make if the msg.sender is not a tx.origin? And in which cases are msg.sender and tx.origin not the same address?

When could this pose a security risk? Or what is the reason for using msg.sender == tx.origin? Doesn't that prevent the interoperability with smart contracts in some cases (you could not build a smart contract that builds on top of the previous contract that requires msg.sender == tx.origin)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between 'msg.sender' and 'tx.origin'?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin)

Answer (score 10):

As you may know, smart contracts cannot send signed transactions, they can only react to them. Smart contract code is triggered by transactions originating from Externally Owned Accounts (EOA).

`tx.origin` is the address of the EOA from which originates the transaction. While `msg.sender` is the address of the account from which the current call is coming from which could be an EOA or a Contract Account (CA).

> What is the purpose of it?

Ensuring that the current caller is an EOA, not a CA.

> When should you add this code?

This could be a security mechanism to ensure that no contract could try to exploit a vulnerability if you later make a call on msg.sender. But It also locks out every CA from interacting with your contract... Not sure if there is another use to it.

> What difference does it make if the msg.sender is not a tx.origin? And
> in which cases are msg.sender and tx.origin not the same address?

If `msg.sender` is not `tx.origin` your direct caller is most definitely a smart contract.

If a user A sends a tx calling a smart contract B, msg.sender == tx.origin == user A address. If contract B makes an external call to contract C then msg.sender == contract B while tx.origin is still user  A.

> When could this pose a security risk?

I don't see a security risk here but maybe someone might know of one ? It's at least an extremely severe limitation. As you pointed out, any smart contract calling on your code would instantly revert since msg.sender would not equal to tx.origin.

Comment: could you maybe answer this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144965/what-type-of-eoa-can-meet-the-condition-tx-origin-msg-sender