# Send ERC20 tokens(it is link) from an address to smart contract

Tags: solidity, transfer

I can not transfer ERC20 tokens from my address to the contract. But I can transfer from the contract to other addresses.

my account(msg.sender) has 10 link(ERC20) tokens . and i want to send these tokens to contract

i am using remix and rinkeby network - metamask
this is my code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
contract TransferTokens {
function transferToMe(address _token, uint _amount) public {
    //token is chainlink_ERC20 address
    //i have links in mo account
    IERC20(_token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
}
```

}

the error is The transaction execution will likely fail

Comment: If you're calling `transferFrom` function, you're doing so on behalf of the `msg.sender`. This action needs to have prior approval using `approve` or `increaseAllowance` function as defined in: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc20#ERC20-approve-address-uint256-

Comment: @StanislavSvědiroh Hello thanks for your answer. i used approve before transferFrom but it doesn't work still

Comment: There is something wrong with your logic. Msg.sender will be address of the smart contract (transferTokens), and address(this) is also the address of the smart contract (transferTokens), so you are transfering tokens from an address to the same address.

Comment: @JoãoPauloMorais You're mistaken. `transferToMe` function is called externally (wallet or a different contract) hence `msg.sender` is not `TransferTokens`. As far as I understood the question, this function works. The thing OP needs to accomplish is to successfully send tokens TO this smart contract.

Comment: TransferToMe is called externally, but then the Smart contract calls another contract, so the msg.sender will be the address of the contract. Please look at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin

Comment: Stanislav Svědiroh
My answer solved . thank you 
create an answer i want to rate you my friend