# Distinguish between function calls from externally owned accounts, and from another smart contracts

Tags: solidity, accounts, function

I wanted to know how to distinguish between a function call from an externally owned user account and a function call from another smart contract in solidity. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check if tx.origin == msg.sender. In this case msg.sender must be an externally owned account. Otherwise msg.sender can't be an externally owned account.

Check [What's the difference between 'msg.sender' and 'tx.origin'?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin)