# Is it possible to call another contract from a contract maintaining the msg.sender of the original caller?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, evm, contract-invocation

Imagine that Alice calls a contract method C1 and that method calls another method in contract C2.

Regularly `msg.sender` equals the Alice Account in the C1 method. And  `msg.sender` equals the C1 contract address in the C2 method.

I would like to know if it is possible to call C2 in such a way that `msg.sender` is still the Alice address instead of C1 address. And that C2 can access C2's state variables.

I have tried to use `delegatecall` and `callcode`, but those functions seems that C2 has only access to the C1 state but not the C2 state. I guess that those calls are more prepared for libraries.

It would be good to have an example of this call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoke contract B from A and preserve msg.sender](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29582/invoke-contract-b-from-a-and-preserve-msg-sender)

Comment: Imagine you ask an exchange to send ether to a smart contract you created, you would be able to transfer tokens stored on behalf of the address sending ethers. Most exchange stores ether and and ERC20 tokens at the same address.

Comment: @user2284570 You have mark the new question as duplicate of the old. Also the answers here are better.

Comment: @jbaylina what happens when you try to delegatecall C1 from C2 ? Why it doesn’t works ?

Answer (score 9):

> I have tried to use delegatecall and callcode, but those functions seems that C2 has only access to the C1 state but not the C2 state.

Correct.

If you want C2's state, you can use `tx.origin` or make C2's method take an extra `address _caller` [(example)](https://github.com/nexusdev/dappsys/blob/809ee37779fa88270bfc31ced1b001aa9f4751ee/contracts/token/controller.sol#L21) that C1 passes Alice's address.  C2 then uses `_caller` instead of `msg.sender`.

Using `tx.origin` means that Alice [can't be a contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1891/42) and [How do I make my DAPP "Serenity-Proof?"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/196/how-do-i-make-my-dapp-serenity-proof/200#200) suggests to avoid using `tx.origin`.

Answer (score 4):

If all you want to know is the originator of the original transaction (as opposed to the current call), you can simply refer to `tx.origin` instead of `msg.caller`.

Comment: It's a good answer! but I let it open because I'm finding some thing that can be done in the C1 as C2 is already deployed.