# deletegateCall to change contract's ownership

Tags: solidity, delegatecall

I am currently going deep into some Solidity functionalities and I would like to be able to change a contract's A ownership from a contract B, knowing that the caller of contract B is the owner of contract A. so he has the right to do it.

Basically, I am creating a Consortium contract that has an owner who is able to add and remove members to the Consortium. Once a member is added, a new Organization contract is created for him. An `Organization` is `Ownable` and the owner should be the new member and not the `Consortium` contract, so I immediately transfer the ownership to the member.

Then, I would like to create a function updateMember where the member could change the ownership of his organization directly via the function. I tried using delegateCall without success... Here is the code for Consortium.

The interesting functions are `addMember` and `updateMember`

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/lifecycle/Destructible.sol";
import "./Organization.sol";

contract Consortium is Destructible {

    /* --- Structures and variables --- */
    struct Member {
        string name;
        address member;
        Organization organization;
        uint since;
    }

    mapping (address => uint) public memberId;
    Member[] public members;

    /* --- Events --- */
    event MembershipChanged(address member, bool isMember);

    /* --- Modifiers --- */
    modifier onlyMembers {
        require(memberId[msg.sender] != 0);
        _;
    }

    /* --- Public functions --- */

    /**
     * Constructor function
     */
    function Consortium() public {
        addMember(owner, "Consortium Funder");
    }

    /**
     * Add member
     *
     * Make `targetMember` a member named `memberName`
     *
     * @param _targetMember ethereum address to be added
     * @param _memberName public name for that member
     */
    function addMember(address _targetMember, string _memberName) onlyOwner public returns(bool) {
        uint id = memberId[_targetMember];
        if (id == 0) {
            memberId[_targetMember] = members.length;
            id = members.length++;
        }

        Organization org = new Organization(_memberName);
        org.transferOwnership(_targetMember);
        members[id] = Member({name: _memberName, member: _targetMember, organization: org, since: now});
        emit MembershipChanged(_targetMember, true);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Update member name
     * @param _name public name for that member
     */
    function updateMemberName(string _name) onlyMembers public returns (bool) {
        members[memberId[msg.sender]].name = _name;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Update member
     * @param _name public name for that member
     * @param _memberAddress ethereum address to be added
     */
    function updateMember(string _name, address _memberAddress) onlyMembers public returns (bool) {
        Member storage member = members[memberId[msg.sender]];
        member.name = _name;
        address orgAddress = address(member.organization);
        orgAddress.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("transferOwnership(address)")), _memberAddress);
        member.member = _memberAddress;
        emit MembershipChanged(_memberAddress, true);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Remove member 
     *
     * @notice Remove membership from `msg.sender` called by member itself
     */
    function removeMember() onlyMembers public {
        for (uint i = memberId[msg.sender]; i < members.length-1; i++){
            members[i] = members[i+1];
        }
        memberId[msg.sender] = 0;
        delete members[members.length-1];
        members.length--;
    }

    /**
     * Remove member
     *
     * @notice Remove membership from `targetMember` called by owner
     *
     * @param _targetMember ethereum address to be removed
     */
    function removeMember(address _targetMember) onlyOwner public {
        require(memberId[_targetMember] != 0);

        for (uint i = memberId[_targetMember]; i < members.length-1; i++){
            members[i] = members[i+1];
        }
        memberId[_targetMember] = 0;
        delete members[members.length-1];
        members.length--;
    }

    /**
     * Check if passed address is a Member
     *
     * @param _targetMember address to check
     */
    function isMember(address _targetMember) public view returns (bool) {
        return memberId[_targetMember] != 0;
    } 

    /**
     * Returns the number of members in the consortium
     */
    function numMembers() public view returns (uint) {
        return members.length;
    }
}
```

Also feel free to criticize this contract if you think my whole approach is not optimal.

Thank you !

Comment: It seems the member can get the address of their Organization from the Consortium. Why not have the user call `Organization.transferOwnership` directly?

Comment: Yes that's a possibility but I was wondering if this could be done in a single call since `delegatecall` has been created for that purpose. It's just that here my call to `delegatecall` doesn't seems to work (event though there are no errors, the owner is not changed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using tx.origin. If the owner of A tries to execute a transaction from B to change the ownership of A then:

1. msg.sender will be B contract's address
2. tx.origin will be the address of who is executing the function in B.

So the `transferOwnership` of A can simply require for:

`require(msg.sender==contractBAddress && tx.origing==owner)`

Other solution is that you can change the `transferOwnership` function to receive an extra parameter as suggested [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin)

EDIT:

One more thing, in [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin) is recommended not to use tx.origin unless strictly necessary. This is because your contract will not be able to be owned by another contract but in your case, this is not a problem. Just take into consideration that some wallets are contracts.

I am adding this just for completeness of the answer.

you can find more information on these links:

[Likn1-dated 2016](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/196/how-do-i-make-my-dapp-serenity-proof)

[Link2-dated 2018](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43195/how-to-avoid-using-tx-origin-when-we-really-need-it)

Comment: Nice! That's a perfect solution. So I need to actually modify the transferOwnership code but that's okay. Thanks !

Comment: I just updated the answer, adding information on being careful using tx.origing if you plan that one contract will be the owner of another contract. I know this is not your case but is important to have this in mind.

Comment: If someone tricks the owner into sending a transaction to a contract which then calls `transferOwnership` checking `tx.origin`, the ownership can be stolen. I'd strongly advise against it. [See docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security-considerations.html?highlight=tx.origin)

Comment: Agree, the solution would be to have both rquirements:   require(msg.sender == contractB_address && tx.origin == owner) or just to pass an extra parameter from B to the function in A after verifying that msg.sender is the owner of A. I added this in the answer.

Comment: I understand... It is indeed problematic.