# DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. But already declared

Tags: solidity, remix

[image]

DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.on line 8,12,14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_success` is not defined anywhere. Is just a parameter of the event `isNotify` but is not a field neither in your function nor in your contract.

So you need to define your local field and then use it to emit the event.

```
function register(string _name) public {
    bool _success = false;
    if (nameToAddress[_name] == address(0)) {
        nameToAddress[_name] = msg.sender;
        _success = true;
    }

    emit isNotify(_success);
}
```

please note that `tx.oring` is not safe to use, better to use `msg.sender`; more info [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin) and [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/196/how-do-i-make-my-dapp-serenity-proof).