# msg.sender and tx.origin - how to use them in practice?

Tags: contract-design, security

I wrote a contract A that uses `msg.sender` for authentication: When A creates an item it stores `msg.sender` in `itemsOwners` mapping (`itemOwners[itemId] = msg.sender;`). Later A compares `msg.sender` to `itemOwners[itemId]` to check access rights.

Now I have the trouble that I cannot use my contract B to wrap calls to A, because A wrongly assumes that the item owner is the contract B, when B calls A. So it stores a wrong item owner that should be a user, not contract B.

Should I replace `msg.sender` by `tx.origin` in A? Or what to do? It was not recommended to use `tx.origin`. So?

I ask not what is the difference between `msg.sender` and `tx.origin`, but *what to do?*

Comment: @goodvibration No.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make my DAPP “Serenity-Proof?”](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/200/16043)?

Comment: @goodvibration No.

Comment: @porton What's the relationship between A and B? Do they work together? If A and B trust each other a typical solution is to pass the user as an address parameter, and A has the requirement that only B can call such method.

Comment: @porton Also the title is a bit misleading, you do not want to know the difference but how to authenticate a user between contracts calls or something like that.

Comment: @Ismael The trouble is that B is _not_ trusted.

Comment: @porton It is an interesting problem. In a similar situation we had a ERC 721 token A that we cannot modify, and we wrote B as a sort of delegate. For A the token's owner was B, and B kept an internal mapping from users to tokens and A never knew about that mapping. Obviously if A is a different contract the same solution might no apply as it is. Unfortunately I don't know a solution that will apply in a more general situation.