# Trouble using delegatecall to pass msg.sender to another contract

Tags: solidity, erc-721

I'm trying to mint an NFT token in contract B by calling a method on contract A, but I want msg.sender (in contract B) to be the address that calls the function on A, not contract A's address.

I thought this should work, but it doesn't. (it reverts on onlyOwner(), etherscan says: Although one or more Error Occurred [Reverted] Contract Execution Completed)

What am I doing wrong here? If I remove onlyOwner on safeMint, it works. So it's definitely a problem with delegatecall. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
    contract A {
        using Counters for Counters.Counter;
        using SafeMath for uint256;
        Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
        address public nftContract;

        constructor(address _nftContract) public {
         nftContract = _nftContract;
        }

        function mintItem() public returns (uint256) {
                _tokenIds.increment();
        
                uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
    
    nftContract.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("safeMint(address,uint256)",msg.sender,newItemid));
                }
}

contract B is ERC721 {

    address public owner;
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    constructor(string memory name,string memory ticker,string memory uri) ERC721(name,ticker) public {
      owner = msg.sender;
      _setBaseURI(uri);
    }

    function safeMint(address to, uint256 tokenId) public onlyOwner{
      _mint(to, tokenId);
    }

}
```

Comment: You're passing `msg.sender` as the first argument to function `safeMint`, not as its actual caller! What made you think it would somehow "become" the `msg.sender` when that function is called? For example, what did you think would happen to the second argument that you are passing?

Comment: And BTW, you're obviously much better off that way, otherwise, anyone else could just as well "forge" the caller (`msg.sender`) and call your `onlyOwner` protected function.

Comment: How to pass it as it's caller? I do need to pass it as the first argument too...

Comment: Read my second comment above.

Comment: If you want `contract A` to be the owner of the contract which implements this function, then you need to create that contract from a function in `contract A`.

Comment: If someone else would call it, it would revert, because the caller is not owner. Anyway, this is a mock example, on contract A there is a check, it's actually an internal function, but that's not really relevant for why delegatecall does not do what I expect it to do.

Comment: Yes, but if you could forge it like the way you are trying to, then so could anyone else. They would simply pass your address instead of their own address! I've explained to you what your delegate call does, and why you cannot forge the address of the caller (aka `msg.sender`). Hope you understand that, because it's a pretty fundamental concept in the Ethereum blockchain.

Comment: I think you are confusing call with delegatecall, see the schematics here: https://medium.com/coinmonks/delegatecall-calling-another-contract-function-in-solidity-b579f804178c#:~:text=DelegateCall%2C%20as%20the%20name%20implies,contract%20but%20on%20caller%20contract.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112621/discussion-between-hdries-and-goodvibration).

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `delegatecall` for your use case except if you want to modify `contract A` storage and not `contract B`. Generally, do not use `delegatecall` unless you really know what you are doing.

You should use `tx.origin` if you want the initial sender of the tx and not the function caller (here contract B).

You can modify your `require` like that:

```
modifier onlyOwner() {
     require(owner == msg.sender || owner == tx.origin, "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
     _;
}
```

Comment: Vitalik himself, in the flesh (or at least in the digitized flash), recommended [not to use tx.origin](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/200/16043).

Comment: I ended up not using delegatecall, and in contract B I've set contract A address as allowed to call safeMint in contract B.